# How to intercept /signin-facebook?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

My user signs in on my website. OWIN handles the Facebook signin. Under the hood it redirects to /signin-facebook?code=some_code, it extracts some_code, posts a request to Facebook for an access_token and returns the access_token to me.

I want to intercept some_code. I want to pass some_code to my WebAPI. My WebAPI should then get the Facebook access_token as well. If that is successful, my WebAPI should return a custom_token (not the Facebook access_token). I want to add my custom_token to the ClaimsIdentity as well, so that my website can call my WebAPI.

Is there some way to intercept some_code in the OWIN middleware?

(Edit: Please note, I am not using .Net Core, I'm using ASP.Net MVC 5 with Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0)

Comment: Can you not just pass the facebook token to your web api as well and then generate the custom_token from that? Then your web api can just return it

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. If you want to do this, you have to roll your own. I ended up writing code that does all the calls to facebook.com, parses the response and passes this on.